# Old horror movie with mutated ape-like people

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I can not figure this out please help.  All I remember is that these strange fruits mutates people into these ape-like creatures. The "fruit" would open up and spray people with some kind of white substance. I think there were four different kinds of fruit and these monsters had unique abilities. The only ability I can remember is one of them could ball up and roll around. That's all I can remember about the movie. It's live action. English in color. Saw it around 1990 so probably an 80's horror movie.

Comment: Live action or cartoon? When did you see it? Was it in English? B&W or colour?

Comment: Live action. Around 1990. Was in English and color.  Was like a B horror movie

Comment: Can you edit the question and add that in? It will help pinpointing it. Still doesn't trigger any memories for me, sorry.

Comment: Ok Thanks. It's been bugging me for a while now.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the movie is *Seedpeople-The Root of All Evil* (1992).

It has an alien tree monster (queen) which grows from a meteorite and infests a grove in Comet Valley.  Several locals get infected by spores and/or goo which sprays from the "fruit" of the tree. The infected people mutate into three main types of grotesque, almost cartoonish mutant monsters.  The human-plant hybrids are described as "shooters," "fliers" and "tumblers," and the latter do indeed "ball up and roll around."  It was produced by Charles Band, who also brought us Ghoulies, The Puppetmaster series, the Subspecies series and many other outrageous B- movies.

Here's a link to a great review with photos on John's Horror Corner:
http://moviesfilmsandflix.com/2013/09/29/johns-horror-corner-seed-people-1992-the-root-of-all-evil/

Comment: I just decided to come back to check on this after a couple of months but OMG Thank you so much. You have no idea how long I've been looking. I knew as soon as I saw the pic that it was the right movie because I instantly remembered that on the VHS cover. I thought one could fly but wasn't as sure as the tumbler one.

Comment: @JerryMorgan If the answer was helpful, please 'accept' it as the **correct** answer by clicking on the 'tick' icon!

Comment: When I read descriptions like this, it makes me wonder if the movie was based on some actually sophisticated "hard-science" science fiction where, for example, the author actually had a background in biology. The written work probably was lot better than the movie because of primitive special effects or lack of description that the written story can actually go into.

Comment: If it _is_ Seedpeople, this might be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255811/late-80s-early-90s-scifi-horror-movie-about-a-group-of-young-people-dealing-wi/255853#255853.