# Late '80s/early '90s scifi/horror movie about a group of young people dealing with an infection/virus that turns one of their friends into a killer

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm looking for help finding a specific late 80s/early 90s scifi horror movie. The things I remember is that it follows a group of either teens or early 20s people in some kind of town and dealing with some kind of infection/virus that turns one of their friends into a killing creature. One scene that is remembered is the group finds a person/friend of theirs hanging from a pod on a sign on the side of a hotel that you'd see around that time. There's also a scene where the friend turns into a creature and they try to reason with the turned, then the turned kills someone. I also remember the pods looked like a disgusting ball of meat.

It was on VHS so it could be older than when I remember seeing it in the mid-90s. I don't remember a whole lot about the monster's appearance, but I seem to remember a scene where a person hid in a car but the creature was already inside of the car and killed that person. I believe it was human-sized but I'm not sure if it was more human than alien (like Predator) or vice versa (like a xenomorph). I remember it took place over one night, it didn't have much involvement from the military or scientists, and it wasn't a big film in terms of budget.

Anyone looking to give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this movie? Also, can you describe the appearance of the creature the friend was transformed into?

Comment: I want to say I remember the movie from the mid-90s, and it was on VHS so it could be older than when I remember seeing it. I don't remember a whole lot about the monster's appearance, but I seem to remember a scene where a person hid in a car but the creature was already inside of the car and killer that person. I believe it was human-sized but I'm not sure if it was more human than alien (like Predator) or vice versa (like a xenomorph). I remember it took place over one night, it didn't have much involvement from the military or scientists, and it wasn't a big film in terms of budget.

Answer (score 3):

This is a *huge* stretch, but maybe it's "[Seedpeople](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105347/?ref_=ttls_li_tt)". It was released in 1992. Here's the plot synopsis, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seedpeople):

> Seed pods from space land in the area surrounding a small rural town, and the seeds become alien creatures that contaminate the human population in the area, turning people into unwilling seed pods that in turn hatch into even more monsters.

The whole film is on [Tubi](https://tubitv.com/movies/478272/seedpeople).

What fits:

- It's low budget. Very.
- The aliens infect/replace/control people, and can shapeshift between human and alien
- It was definitely available on VHS in the mid 90s
- Several of the characters are in their 20s
- Takes place in a small town
- No military presence

What doesn't:

- I can't find any scenes that quite fit your description of someone hanging from a sign
- I can't find a scene where someone is attacked in a car